# how to upload image using image picker and display it on another page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image, imagepicker

I have a question about how to upload an image using an image picker and display it on another page. in this code, I am uploading 5 images but I don't know how to display that 5 uploaded images on another page. I created model for images uploading. hope you understand the question. please help me I am stuck very much at this point. you help can make my day.

Here is code I've tried. your help will be appreciated.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

import 'package:tudo/src/modules/bsp_signup/bsp_signup_common_model.dart';
import 'package:tudo/src/modules/bsp_signup/business_profile/business_profile_page.dart';
import 'package:tudo/src/styles/colors.dart';
import 'package:tudo/src/utils/navigation_helper.dart';

class BspLicensedSignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/bspLicensedSignup";

  final BspSignupCommonModel bspSignupCommonModel;

  BspLicensedSignupPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.bspSignupCommonModel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BspLicensedSignupPageState createState() => _BspLicensedSignupPageState();
}

class _BspLicensedSignupPageState extends State<BspLicensedSignupPage> {
  List<Object> images = List<Object>();
  Future<File> _imageFile;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    debugPrint(
        'BSP SIGNUP DATA: ${widget.bspSignupCommonModel.businessLegalAddress}');
    setState(() {
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
      images.add("Add Image");
    });
  }

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  int radioValue = -1;
  File _image;

  Future<File> licenceimage;
  Future<File> profilepicture;
  picklicensepicture(ImageSource source) {
    setState(() {
      licenceimage = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    });
  }

  pickprofilepicture(ImageSource source) {
    setState(() {
      profilepicture = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> bspsignupdata = new Map<String, dynamic>();

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget _buildbusinesslicensepicture() {
    return GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 5,
      childAspectRatio: 1,
      children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
        if (images[index] is ImageUploadModel) {
          ImageUploadModel uploadModel = images[index];
          return Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.file(
                  uploadModel.imageFile,
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right: 5,
                  top: 5,
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.remove_circle,
                      size: 20,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        images.replaceRange(index, index + 1, ['Add Image']);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Card(
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                _onAddImageClick(index);
              },
            ),
          );
        }
      }),
    );
  }

  Future _onAddImageClick(int index) async {
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      getFileImage(index);
    });
  }

  void getFileImage(int index) async {
    _imageFile.then((file) async {
      setState(() {
        ImageUploadModel imageUpload = new ImageUploadModel();
        imageUpload.isUploaded = false;
        imageUpload.uploading = false;
        imageUpload.imageFile = file;
        imageUpload.imageUrl = '';
        images.replaceRange(index, index + 1, [imageUpload]);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("BSP Licensed Signup"),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            NavigationHelper.navigatetoBack(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 56,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowCircleRight),
              label: Text('Next'),
              color: colorStyles["primary"],
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  BspSignupCommonModel model = widget.bspSignupCommonModel;
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          BusinessProfilePage(bspSignupCommonModel: model),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            // Background(),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: SafeArea(
                top: false,
                bottom: false,
                child: Form(
                  autovalidate: true,
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Scrollbar(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                      child: new Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 30, 30, 0),
                        child: new Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            _buildbusinesslicensepicture(),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageUploadModel {
  bool isUploaded;
  bool uploading;
  File imageFile;
  String imageUrl;

  ImageUploadModel({
    this.isUploaded,
    this.uploading,
    this.imageFile,
    this.imageUrl,
  });
}
```